# How to pass/inject "text" inside the URL in react-router v3?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to pass a video ID to my URL.

Let's assume the user is on page where all the videos are listed:
Video1
Video2
Video3
Video4

and the current URL is "/videos"

Now, if the user clicks on any of the video, i want to push that selected video id to the URL.

new URL: "/videos?id=Video1"

I'm currently using react-router v3

```
<Route component={HomePage}>
 <IndexRoute component={AssetPage}/>
 <Route path='/assets' component={AssetPage}/>
 <Route path='/video' component={VideoPage}/>
 <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Please share your code snippet as well

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala I have updated the question. I want to pass data from `<VideoPage />` component to this `<Route path="/video?id=someid" />`

Comment: You can add `<Link to="/video?id="+videoId>button</Link>`
Where your `videoId` is the dynamic id generated from the list of videos you have passed.

Comment: Oh okay, got it. Thanks :D